# Security: $_SERVER array sql injection in PHP

Tags: php, security, header-injection

I have written a PHP function that records everything in the `$_SERVER` array and if there is a certain `$_SERVER` variable that doesn't exist in my Database, it will add that column.

My question is this: How secure does this sound to you? After research and understanding of the header information some questions arise.

1. Would a client be able to modify certain variables sent to the server their their browser agent or OS?
2. Would someone who would be hosting a site from their own server be able to insert code into their own custom `$_SERVER` array?

Overall, I'm just asking exactly how secure this sounds, but those were the first concerns that comes to mind.

If you find anything wrong with the way I asked this question, please comment before you down-vote and I will change it immediately.

Comment: The webserver determines what is in `$_SERVER`, if you trust your webserver you can trust `$_SERVER`. Why do you want to log everything in `$_SERVER`? Most of it is useless information.

Comment: Just for my own statistics and curiosity. It would be going on hundreds of web servers, some of which I wouldn't know the owner of.

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea. I wouldn't do what you're trying to do. I'd look for a different solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Im not trying to necessarily solve a problem, I'm just trying to collect information. Are there any specific reasons that you have in mind that would make you think this in unsecure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$_SERVER` can **not** be trusted. `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` contains a String that is easily user-configurable - SQL Injection possible. There are even browser plugins for that purpose. In fact, there are a lot of `$_SERVER` vars that can be changed by the user, for example also `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`.

Have a look at the Chrome plugin [ModHeader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj):

[image]

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for! So here is my follow up question:

 Suppose I use a prepared statement or escape the strings to store the Data in my SQL server, Would I still be vulnerable to Injection?

 I understand that it would do nothing against data skewing however...

Comment: I am using [prepared statements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/4193263) in my projects. You will not be vulnerable to SQL Injection when using prepared statements, see the answer I linked to for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The $_SERVER variable is used by PHP to return information about the  server based information, it is not a place to store data. To be honest, it's first time to hear that somebody wants to use $_SERVER superglobal to store data. Maybe  you should use $_SESSION ? I think that's the right way for storing data if database is not an option...

Also $_SERVER array seems to refresh each time you reload a page. And what @ByteHamster pointed some of values in $_SERVER variable can be tampered.

The point is that you are trying to use something which is not designed for that purpose...

Comment: I'm not using it to store data, just collect it and store it into a SQL server and later analyze it. Thank you for the answer though!